# deploy a site from repo branch in git

Tags: git

So I've begun using git and I want to create a script that deploys a specific branch...

my file structure usually has a repos folder below the document_root where my repo's for a specific site is located... and then I have the public_html folder there as well..

Keep in mind I've been using git and everything for about 4 days now...

So i'm thinking my command would be something like:

`git deploy <branch> <location to deploy to>`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to look at the `git archive` command.

For instance:

```
~/site1-repo $ git archive master | tar -xC /path/to/site1/public_html
```

would export the contents of the master branch of the repo at `~/site1-repo`, into the public_html folder of site1.

Comment: Nice Idea..  Haven't seen this command before...  Though doing something like this, wouldn't it make an archive(in this case a tar) of the branch instead of just copying the files from the specified branch to the document root?

Comment: `git archive` creates a tar-format stream by default... hence why it's piped to `tar -x` which extracts that stream (and the `-C <path>` tells it where to extract it to).

Comment: (The `git archive <ref> | tar -xC <path>` pattern is a very, very common one.)

Comment: does the path need to be relative on the server or would i be able to do like:  git archive master | tar -xC ~/public_html ?

Comment: You can use any path that your current execution environment can resolve.

Comment: This didn't work for exactly how I expected it..  This seems to only do it on the localhost -- and for some reason i can't run git commands via ssh -- so i started looking at the command and came up with: `git archive --format=tar master | gzip -9c | ssh user@domain.com "cd public_html; tar xvzf -"` which does exactly what i want it to do..  though it's a bit rough to remember...

Comment: One option is that you can put a bare repository on your remote server (*not* in your webserver's root, but elsewhere) and then put a `post-receive` hook in it (see `man githooks` for details) that runs the `git archive` command. If you do that, then you can just push to that repository and the hook can run the archive directly on your server.

Comment: (Note that your question did not actually state that you wanted to deploy code to a remote server.)

Comment: Well I can't really do that hook thing...  Because every time I push, I don't deploy it to the public_html...  So i'd have to figure out how to write a custom git command in order to make it happen...  but it works with the command i gave.. so thats good enough for now.. thanks for putting me on track.

Answer (score -1):

Make the deployment target a git clone itself

```
git clone master:/path/to/repo
```

Now you only need

```
git pull
```

to update. If you need additional "logic" (for example cleaning caches or something), you can create the corresponding `.git/hooks/post-merge` script

Comment: Putting a `.git` directory in the document root is a bad idea. `git archive` was designed for precisely this kind of task.

Comment: @Amber Don't be stupid. I never said "document root", which is _obviously_ a bad idea.